# How can I strip compiler information from PE?

Tags: lazarus, freepascal, portable-executable

is there a simple way to strip compiler information from PE file?
[image: Exeinfo PE]

Comment: I doubt that that string is literally in the PE binary. (e.g. the "v2.x" bit would never be put in a binary by a v3.x compiler). Most likely, exeinfo checks a bunch of markers and then combines them into that string.

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort, I found "FPC 3.0.4 [2017/12/03] for x86_64 - Win64" string in PE, also "Lazarus LCL: 1.8.0.6 - FPC: 3.0.4". I can't figure out which units are responsible for this.

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort, also it's quite interesting that when I compile with GDB information Exeinfo PE shows "64 bit executable -> *** Unknown EXE  - CPU : AMD  Std Compiler section  [ 12 ] sections Overlay : 000000... Nothing discovered".

Answer (score 0):

Use the program "strip" which comes with fpc (in fpc/bin).

Comment: I tried to use it with every option and it does not work. Any hint, please?

Comment: I'm sorry: I confused your question with "debugger information".

Comment: *I confused your question*. That means this answer does not apply and should be deleted, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes. But if I delete it what will happen with the comments following it? Will they be gone? if yes - fine, but why can I delete something which somebody else wrote? If not - the result will be very confusing to the reader.

Answer (score 0):

The lazarus one needs to be in the units though (lclbase?), maybe the FPC one too (compiler/version.pas would be my guess). But potentially grepping is difficult because the strings might be made with {$i %%} [include meta data](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/prog/progsu41.html) constructs.

To work around this, and at least get the unit, one could also try to compile everything to assembler (-a -s), and then grep the generated assembler. The assembler will contain the final form

Strings can also get added by the linker, on Windows, FPC typically uses its internal (high speed) linkers.You can try to use the external (GNU LD) linker (-Xe) to see if that behaves differently.